# How to return a string in function in native module in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, objective-c, react-native

I am working on a function related to the native part of ios written in Object-C,

I want to write a method that returns a string in Object-C,

but I am facing a problem when I write this method:
`Expected selector for Objective-C method`,

My code is as follows:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD((NSString *)getName)
{
  return "Sammeme";
}
@end
```

Anyone doing ios development can help me to solve this problem,

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: when I write the above method it throws an exception as: ```Expected selector for Objective-C method ```, so I want to solve it. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Is this the complete code? Is there also an `@start` somewhere? Is this in a class? Could you show the rest of the class?

Answer (score 1):

In your Implementation file, inside of your RCT_EXPORT_METHOD, in order to return a **value** you can either use a promise or a callback. I like to use a promise:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(returnStringFromNativeModule:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    resolve(@"This is a value returned from a Native Module");
}
```

and in your React Native code, this is how you would call your method:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';


const { myNativeModule } = NativeModules;
const myString = await myNativeModule.returnStringFromNativeModule();
```